# WebRTC Public Kiosk Security Model

Tags: security

I am diving into WebRTC to make a basic one-to-one video/audio connection between two endpoints.  I am now struggling to determine what would be an advisable security model in the following situation:

- The WebRTC application is a Chrome extension running in "Kiosk Mode" (I realize there would need to be more done on the OS / peripheral perspective to make this secure).  Basically treat this as a public telephone booth any person can walk up to unattended (like the one on the space station in 2001 A Space Odyssey).
- There should be no requirement to enter a password or unique identifier to identify the person.  The kiosk hardware and location itself is what needs to be confirmed in order to remotely send commands.  Once a public user initiates a "call", the call will always go to one place.
- For now, I will simplify by saying that there is a single, NON-public endpoint which is behind a controlled firewall.

What is the best way to reliably and securely identify the public kiosk when it initiates a call?  I feel like I am overthinking this problem, but my understanding is that obtaining a device MAC address from javascript is inherently insecure or not allowed.

I need some suggestions to point me in the right direction or tell me this is a horrible idea.

Comment: Have you considered using a VPN?

Comment: Doesn't a VPN still require a user authentication step?  I am not very familiar with VPN techniques.

Comment: Authenetication.. yes.  Nothing stopping you from having that done in a script at boot automatically.

Comment: Yes, but how does one go about doing that?  In an encrypted file?  A TPM (Trusted Platform Module)?  What is the method of extracting that information and securely passing that into my application -- while minimizing the chances of that kiosk being spoofed?

Comment: So, for example, how does a server uniquely identify an ATM when someone goes to make a transaction?  They are authenticating with a card, fine... but doesn't the ATM machine need to send its location and hardware securely and separately from the user's ID/pin?

Comment: Why would you need to identify it uniquely when someone makes a transaction?  You establish a VPN using different credentials for each end-device on startup.  That's assuming an always-on network connection but it would work pretty much the same on-demand.  Now you've uniquely identified each ATM and I suspect you already know the location of it.